# Push from lambda to S3 or push from lambda to Kinesis Firehose to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I see in many architecture diagrams, that instead of pushing data  directly from lambda to S3, we push it from lambda to Kinesis Firehose to S3. Is there any pros/cons of doing either way?

Comment: It would help if you showed those architecture diagrams. It largely depends on the size of the data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: What type of data is being transferred? If it is lots of streaming data (eg small packets of event data), then Amazon Kinesis Firehose can collect multiple records together by size or time, then store it in S3. If you did it directly from Lambda you would need to store each record in its own object within S3. That might not be a very efficient way to store data. (It is not possible to append to objects in S3.)